# RmiProxyFactoryBean + Autowired(required=false)

Tags: java, spring, rmi, dependency-management, spring-remoting

I have 5 projects - 4 of which are run on the console (say A,B,C and D) with `java -jar A.jar` etc and 1 web application (E). The web application is deployed on a number of isolated servers some of which also have a combination of A, B, C and D running.

In the spring config file for the web application I have 4 `RmiProxyFactoryBean` declarations, one for each of the projects A, B, C and D where each of these projects have 1 `RmiServiceExporter`.

My problem is that the web application throws an exception on startup if one of the projects (A-D) is not running. I've tried using `@Autowired(required=false)` in the controllers using these services to no avail. To make it work I'm having to go edit the web app spring file to comment out the `RmiProxyFactoryBean` for projects that aren't running. Is there a way of telling an `RmiProxyFactoryBean` to attempt to retrieve the bean and if it fails then don't worry - in much a similar way as `required=false` with the autowire?

My config currently looks like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="service"          ref="diagramAssociationService" />
    <property name="serviceName"      value="diagramAssociationService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.act.xv.service.IDiagramAssociationService"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="diagramAssociationService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://${xv.deploy.location}/diagramAssociationService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.act.xv.service.IDiagramAssociationService"/>
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your RmiProxyFactoryBean also set the lookupStubOnStartup property to "false".  This should prevent the client proxy from throwing an exception on startup.